# How to add a lot of resource files to a monotouch project?

Tags: xamarin.ios, include, project, xamarin

I have a lot of png images into a directory. I've added it to the project as Content/Copy if newer. I can load them from the app without problems.

But, the project needs a lot of time to compile. If i make a little change in the code, the project recompiles all again. It takes a lot of time.

I've tried to add another project, add the files to the new project, but then i can not access to the files from the app.

Is there any solution?

Of course, when i debug the app into the iPad, the uploading+install takes a lot of time.  These files will not change ever, so...Is there any method to copy all the content ONE time?

Thanks

Comment: You actually don't have to set "Copy if newer" in MonoTouch projects, just set build action to "Content".  Does your build time speed up if you change this?

Comment: As jonathanpeppers said, don't set "Copy if newer" (that copies to bin/Debug/iPhone/ and not into the .app directory). Also, BundleResource is preferred over Content.

Answer (score 1):

I just have discovered a tricks. It seems that monotouch does not remove directories when you upload and install from the MonoDevelop environtment, so:

1. Add your folders and all the files and mark them as Content
2. Build your project for iPhone/iPad and Run it from MonoDevelop
3. Remove your data foldres from your porject
4. Clean the solution
5. Make any changes you need in your code, your data reamins in the device!!!

That changes all!!! Before that, when i need to make a minor change in my code, i needed to wait about 15' for building and uploading. Now it's just 1 minute!!!

Comment: Are most of these files pngs that get crushed as part of the build? If so, I've committed a fix to MonoDevelop (unfortunately not in time for 4.0) that will avoid re-copying and re-crushing images if they haven't changed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place your images in a separate class library
2. Mark all your files as embedded resources
3. Add a logical name to each resource (in your project file)

```xml
<EmbeddedResource Include="Images\Folder\Filename.ext">
    <LogicalName>LogicalNameForImage</LogicalName>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

4. Load the resource as

```cs
UIImage.FromResource(yourAssembly, "LogicalNameForImage");
```

Embedded resources are loaded on demand, not when the assembly loads.

Comment: Aha, is a good solution!!! But it forces me to assign logical names, it's a bit complicated, but it can be done from my editor export module.
Thanks!!

Comment: A problem with embedding the images is that you won't be able to take advantage of UIKit's feature to load the correct resolution images (retina vs standard).

Answer (score 0):

In A future version of MonoDevelop (my patch didn't make it in time for the upcoming 4.0 release), this won't be an issue any longer.

What currently happens in MonoDevelop 3.x is that when building a project, it will only copy the images that have changed into the app bundle, *however*, after building, MonoDevelop invokes a script that is installed along with Xcode called `iphone-optimize` which scans the entire app directory and uses `pngcrush` to crush all of the images (it also converts all plist files into binary plists). *This* is the step that causes such slow build times if you have a lot of images.

Just after the 4.0 branch closed for QAing, I wrote a patch that avoids the need for invoking the `iphone-optimize` script. Instead, what MonoDevelop will do is it will directly invoke `pngcrush` on *only* the images that have changed, passing the proper app directory location as the output argument to `pngcrush` so that we avoid an additional file-copy.

From my own testing, this makes a *massive* improvement to build times for projects with a lot of image files.

In the meantime, what you *could* do, is make a backup of the `iphone-optimize` script (should be located somewhere under `/Applications/Xcode.app`) and then modify it to not crush image files. Then, once you've done that, go and pre-crush all of your png files in your project.

(Note: when the MonoDevelop with my patch finally ships, it'll also have an option to disable calling pngcrush for developers who have already pre-crushed their images).